# What does an upside down question mark mean in the output in C?

Tags: c, string

I get an upside down question mark as an output from of of my function, what does it mean exactly?

Comment: Can we see the code generating this output?

Comment: This is a very vague question. It may help if you could show us, what your function actually does or is supposed to do.

Comment: May be bytecode 168 as in http://www.asciitable.com/extend.gif

Answer (score 5):

If it's not at all what you're expecting, it may be something to do with the encoding which your terminal is using, and your program attempting to output text in an encoding which doesn't match. What did you expect to see from your program?

Answer (score 3):

It does not mean anything special in C.  Your function will only output what you program it to do, so if it is not outputting what you expect, you have a bug; simple as that.

Answer (score 3):

That is a Punto de Interogación Inicial. It is used in Spanish to indicate the beginning of a question. In English, questions are easier to identify while reading because word order is often changed for questions. In Spanish that is not the case.

Comment: -1. While it's true that the OP's question lacks sufficient detail, this is not a useful answer and smacks of condescension.

Comment: Well, also in Italian we don't change the word order, but we don't have that punctuation sign...

Comment: I will delete if OP clarifies that I did not answer what he meant to ask.

Comment: @klez, Interesting. This is what I learned in Spanish class. You may consider adopting this convention in Italian. :-)

Answer (score 3):

Do you expect 168 as the result by any chance? It's the [Extended-ASCII code of the upside-down question mark](http://www.asciitable.com/).

Comment: The ASCII standard has only 128 characters, as it needed to be compatible with 7 bit systems. Maybe you mean ISO-8859-1 aka "latin-1"?

Comment: He could well have meant the extended ASCII code (a precursor to the ISO standard 8bit encoding which is common today): http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_ASCII

Comment: @wcoenen: I believe it's 191 in ISO-8859-1, isn't it? "Extended ASCII" is common way to refer to character sets that filled in the 128-255 range. And it's 168 in that set.

Comment: "Extended ASCII" does not define any particular encoding at all, it is just a name for the entire set of 8-bit character sets where the meaning of the first 128 code points is the same as ASCII.  So there is no "Extended-ASCII code of the upside down question mark".